# Opencv program becomes much slower when compiled with the same lib in a new directory

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I wrote a program using Opencv. The program goes correctly but for some reasons, I have to move the Opencv dependencies from the system directory, i.e. `/usr/local/lib/`, to a relative path, say `../third_party/opencv/lib/`. Then I change the `CMakeLists.txt` accordingly to have the program link to the `opencv` in the new directory.

However, after doing this, the compilation is fine. But the program runs 5 times slower than that compiled using the `/usr/local/lib/`. I did not change any single character of the `opencv` library. I just copied it from `/usr/local/lib/` to `../third_party/lib/`, as well as the includes, from `/usr/local/include/opencv` to `../third_party/opencv/include/opencv`, and `/usr/local/include/opencv2` to `../third_party/opencv/include/opencv2`. The following is my `CMakeLists.txt`.

What's wrong with my project?

Thank you all for helping me!

```
#1.cmake verson
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

#2.project name
PROJECT(evaluate)

#3.head file path
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
include
/home/mypath/third_party/opencv/include/opencv
/home/mypath/third_party/opencv/include/opencv2
/home/mypath/third_party/opencv/include
)
SET(OPENCV_DIR /home/mypath/third_party/opencv)

#4.source directory
AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(src DIR_SRCS)

#5.set environment variable
SET(Lane
${DIR_SRCS}
)

#6.add executable file
ADD_EXECUTABLE(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Lane})

SET(OPENCVLIB
        ${OPENCV_DIR}/lib/libopencv_core.so
        ${OPENCV_DIR}/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
        ${OPENCV_DIR}/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so
        ${OPENCV_DIR}/lib/libopencv_video.so
        ${OPENCV_DIR}/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.0
   )

#7.add link library
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OPENCVLIB})
```

I `ldd` the program, the printed information shows that it is linked to the correct path.

But the keypoint is that, the lib in `/usr/local/lib` and that in `/home/mypath/third_party/opencv/lib/`, they are actually the same lib. I just copy it from the first path to the second. Why is the speed so difference?

```
    libopencv_core.so.3.0 => /home/mypath/third_party/opencv/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0 (0x00007f929a43d000)
    libopencv_highgui.so.3.0 => /home/mypath/third_party/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.0 (0x00007f929a231000)
    libopencv_imgproc.so.3.0 => /home/mypath/third_party/opencv/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.0 (0x00007f92992af000)
    libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.0 => /home/mypath/third_party/opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.0 (0x00007f9298f02000)
```

Comment: In debug or release?

Comment: I don't know... I'm not familiar with this. I just mkdir build, cd build, cmake .., make. That's all.

Comment: Run `ldd <your-application>` and make sure that full paths for referenced libraries are expected ones.

Comment: I tried. The path is correct. I updated in the question. @Tsyvarev